# Генерация текста из файла

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, подскажите, как изменить код что бы генерация была не случайная, а из файла, например, в файле есть 100 строк, из файла берется первая строка с КОДОМ1, после КОД2, КОД3 и.т.д

```
function generatePassword($length = 8){
      $chars = 'abdefhiknrstyzABDEFGHKNQRSTYZ23456789';
      $numChars = strlen($chars);
      $string = '';
      for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $string .= substr($chars, rand(1, $numChars) - 1, 1);
      }
      return $string;
    }

          function savek($idt) {
            global $db, $me;
            set_lang_name('items');

            $db->where('item_id', $idt);

            $query = $db->update('items_keys', array(
                'key' => generatePassword(8)
```

Comment: Если коротко, то `file_read_contents(); split();`. А потом из массива берём как хотим.

Comment: @ArchDemon, я просто оставлю это здесь http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php

Comment: @ArchDemon, `file_read_contents` - данной функции не существует, не нужно давать несуществующую информацию и за блуждать пользователей.

Comment: @And, `file_get_contents()` так лучше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно прочитать файл в массив, перемешать элементы массива, и вывести первый его элемент:

```
function generatePassword($file)
{
    $strings = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    shuffle($strings);
    return $strings[0];
}

var_dump(generatePassword('файл.txt'));
```

---

Возможно вам нужен последовательный вывод строк из файла, тогда нужно где-то сохранять состояние счётчика *(в сессии, текст.файле, в БД)*. Для примера я написал сохранение в текст. файле:

```
function generatePassword($file, $count)
{
    $strings = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $all = file_exists($count) ? (int) file_get_contents($count) : 0;

    $string = $strings[$all];

    $all = $all >= (count($strings) - 1) ? 0 : ++$all;    
    file_put_contents($count, $all);

    return $string;
}

var_dump(generatePassword('файл.txt', 'счётчик.txt'));
```